# Any code sample available for fetching data from SAP to sharepoint feature using BCS?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

We require to get data from SAP system in sharepoint 2010 timer job and feature as well custom webparts, reports.

Require walkthrough samples or guidance to achieve the same using BCS.

Answer (score 0):

Harsha,

You can use LINQ to ERP (LINQ TO SAP) and code custom Business Connectivity Model.. Please have a look at:
[How to Integrate SAP Business Data Into SharePoint 2010 Using Business Connectivity Services and LINQ to SAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102453/How-to-Integrate-SAP-Business-Data-Into-SharePoint?msg=4331701)

Here is how to use LINQ TO SAP:
[LINQ to SAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27891/LINQ-to-SAP)

This is one way of doing it, but most preferred and followed method is consuming **SAP Web Services** and create OOB BCS Connection using Web Service model.. It will be easy and will provide more flexibility.. But more work is required on SAP since all data incoming/outgoing will be handled by SAP!